# Int type as Entity key into BCS Model

Tags: bcs, wcf

The BCS Model can't create a form for the "Update" operation if the key of Entity has a type of uint, int, long or ulong when I use WCF as a data source. It works fine with the string type.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Int works from time to time with web service, always with database. Long doesn't work anytime.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set ReadOnly attribute to the identifier in Specific Finder and Finder methods